# Verify signature in openssl c++, which is signed by JAVA DSA?

Tags: java, c++, encryption, openssl

I have a requirement to verify a signature in c++ which is generated by JAVA signature API.
I have the same set of public and private keys. **I have also verified that the signing and verification works in c++**. But I'm having trouble verifying the signature generated by JAVA.
I have looked through the documentations and tried different things, but I still can't seem to figure it out. I'm pasting equivalent c++ code with the original JAVA code used for verification.

Original JAVA code:

```
public static boolean verify(byte[] data, byte[] _signature, byte[] _publicKey) throws GeneralSecurityException {
        Signature signatureInstance = Signature.getInstance("DSA", "SUN");
        signatureInstance.initVerify(getPublicKey(_publicKey));
        signatureInstance.update(data);
        return signatureInstance.verify(_signature);
    }
```

c++ code:

```
//sign_buffer contains the binary signature.

    int ret = DSA_verify(NID_dsa, data, sizeof(data), sign_buffer,
                          sign_length, pubkey);
if (ret != 1) {
            cerr << "verify failed" << endl;
            exit(-1);
        }
```

I have 3 questions:

- Is this the right way to verify the signature?
- Do I need to hash the data before verifying it? If yes then, how does JAVA does it before signing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DSA signature generated by the java code is encoded as ASN.1. Assuming that you have stored it in a file called `sig`, you can verify that using the `openssl asn1parse` command, like this:

```
$ openssl asn1parse -inform der -in sig -i
    0:d=0  hl=2 l=  44 cons: SEQUENCE          
    2:d=1  hl=2 l=  20 prim:  INTEGER           :64C91D32CC10D7B67A7994BE680FA2BB07C431E2
   24:d=1  hl=2 l=  20 prim:  INTEGER           :712F1C768CFFA704DA1BEFA5A36517CB4776E6FF
```

In order to load that kind of formatted signature into the OpenSSL `DSA_SIG` structure, you have to leverage the function [`d2i_DSA_SIG()`](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/man3/d2i_X509.html). Reusing the names of your variables:

```
const unsigned char *ptr = sign_buffer;
DSA_SIG *dsasig = d2i_DSA_SIG(NULL, &ptr, sign_length);
```

The value of `ptr` will be modified to point beyond the bytes that were read, as explained in the documentation.

Indeed you will have to hash your data bytes before verifying, using the same hashing algorithm as used when signing. It seems that `"DSA`" is synonym for `"SHA1withDSA`". I have verified that with a test, but I would recommend to be as explicit as possible in your code and use the full name in stead of some unclear alias. Example code of how to calculate digests with OpenSSL can be found on the [wiki entry EVP Message Digests](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/EVP_Message_Digests).

Then you are finally ready to do the verification

```
verify_result = DSA_do_verify(mdvalue, mdlen, dsasig, dsapubkey);
```

The return code `1` stands for successful verification, `0` stands for failed verification, `-1` is some other error.

It is recommended to use the [`EVP`-level APIs](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/EVP_Signing_and_Verifying) as opposed to the [lower level `DSA`-APIs](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.0.2/crypto/DSA_do_verify.html), but `DSA_do_verify()` seemed closer to where you had gotten already and it works as well.